# RabbitMQ+SpringAMPQ: Broker not available; cannot force queue declarations during start: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, messagebroker

I am currently learning RabbitMQ and Spring AMPQ.
I was trying some examples this week but I am facing an issue in some step of the configuration.

I have this docker-compose file:

```
app:
  build: .
  environment:
    INSERTION_QUEUE: insertion.queue
    VALIDATION_QUEUE: validation.queue
    NUMBER_OF_VALIDATION_CONSUMERS: 1
    RESPONSE_EXCHANGE: response.exchange
    RESPONSE_ROUTING_KEY: response.routing.key
    RABBITMQ_HOST: rabbitmq
    RABBITMQ_PORT: 5672
    RABBITMQ_VHOST: /
    RABBITMQ_USERNAME: guest
    RABBITMQ_PASSWORD: guest
    JDBC_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/hided
  links:
    - mysql:mysql
    - rabbitmq:rabbitmq
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: hided
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
rabbitmq:
  image: rabbitmq:3.6-management
  ports:
    - 15672:15672
```

And I copied this example, adding maven configuration to it: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-rabbitmq/tree/master/complete

The RabbitMQ is accessed through the URL localhost:15672 correctly with username and password "guest"

But when I run this example, it gives me this error (which I believe the important message is **Broker not available; cannot force queue declarations during start: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect**):

```
2020-04-11 04:50:49.202  INFO 25576 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2020-04-11 04:50:51.222  INFO 25576 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Broker not available; cannot force queue declarations during start: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2020-04-11 04:50:51.225  INFO 25576 --- [    container-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2020-04-11 04:50:53.242 ERROR 25576 --- [    container-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:510) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:751) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:214) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2095) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2068) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2048) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueInfo(RabbitAdmin.java:407) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:391) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.attemptDeclarations(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1830) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1811) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.initialize(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1342) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1188) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_241]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60) ~[amqp-client-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1113) ~[amqp-client-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1063) ~[amqp-client-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connect(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:526) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:473) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 12 common frames omitted

2020-04-11 04:50:53.244  INFO 25576 --- [    container-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2020-04-11 04:50:55.266  INFO 25576 --- [           main] c.a.A.AppNameApplication           : Started AppNameApplication in 7.328 seconds (JVM running for 8.175)
Sending message...
2020-04-11 04:50:55.268  INFO 25576 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2020-04-11 04:50:57.285  INFO 25576 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-04-11 04:50:57.293 ERROR 25576 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:787) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.appname.AppName.AppNameApplication.main(AppNameApplication.java:19) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:510) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:751) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:214) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2095) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2068) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:1009) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1075) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1068) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.appname.AppName.Runner.run(Runner.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60) ~[amqp-client-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1113) ~[amqp-client-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1063) ~[amqp-client-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connect(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:526) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:473) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted

2020-04-11 04:50:57.296  INFO 25576 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Waiting for workers to finish.
2020-04-11 04:50:57.296  INFO 25576 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Successfully waited for workers to finish.
2020-04-11 04:50:57.298  INFO 25576 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Shutdown ignored - container is not active already
```

I would like to understand what I am doing wrong, I tried to add the code below to "MessagingRabbitmqApplication.java" to force the connection, made some changes in ports, address, disabled firewall, no success:

```
@Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHost("localhost");
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost("/");
        connectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("guest");
        return connectionFactory;
    }
```

I did try other examples but I keep facing this same error.

My Dockerfile is:

```
# Start with a base image containing Java runtime
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

# Add Maintainer Info
LABEL maintainer="hidden"

# Add a volume pointing to /tmp
VOLUME /tmp

ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

And my application.properties is:

```
#Database properties
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/app_name?user=root&password=secret
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = secret
spring.datasource.platform = mysql
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

#Rabbitmq properties
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
spring.rabbitmq.template.exchange=response.exchange
spring.rabbitmq.template.routing-key=response.routing.key
spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host=/
```

Thank you for your time,
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error today, we need to expose the RabbitMQ port in the docker-compose file or it won't be accessible. So we need to add the line - 5672:5672 in the rabbitmq > ports

```
app:
  build: .
  environment:
    INSERTION_QUEUE: insertion.queue
    VALIDATION_QUEUE: validation.queue
    NUMBER_OF_VALIDATION_CONSUMERS: 1
    RESPONSE_EXCHANGE: response.exchange
    RESPONSE_ROUTING_KEY: response.routing.key
    RABBITMQ_HOST: rabbitmq
    RABBITMQ_PORT: 5672
    RABBITMQ_VHOST: /
    RABBITMQ_USERNAME: guest
    RABBITMQ_PASSWORD: guest
    JDBC_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/hided
  links:
    - mysql:mysql
    - rabbitmq:rabbitmq
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: hided
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
rabbitmq:
  image: rabbitmq:3.6-management
  ports:
    - 5672:5672
    - 15672:15672
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please correct your bean creation configuration you should replace with

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setHost(System.getProperty("RABBITMQ_HOST"));
    connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(System.getProperty("RABBITMQ_VHOST"));
    connectionFactory.setUsername(System.getProperty("RABBITMQ_USERNAME"));
    connectionFactory.setPassword(System.getProperty("RABBITMQ_PASSWORD"));
    return connectionFactory;
}
```

and modify your Dockerfile last line

```
# Start with a base image containing Java runtime
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
# Add Maintainer Info
LABEL maintainer="hidden"

# Add a volume pointing to /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT java -DRABBITMQ_HOST=${RABBITMQ_HOST} -DRABBITMQ_VHOST=${RABBITMQ_VHOST} -DRABBITMQ_USERNAME=${RABBITMQ_USERNAME} -DRABBITMQ_PASSWORD=${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD} -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom  -jar app.jar
```

Comment: Hi Mukhtiar, 

After using these parameters it was not able to find it, maybe some link between my project and the docker-compose file is needed?

I just don't know how.

It has changed the connection phrase to:
Attempting to connect to: null:5672

Comment: I have mode changes the your Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

Got stuck on this error for a couple days.
What worked for me was to include the

```
SPRING_RABBITMQ_SSL_ENABLED=true
```

setting in a `.env` file that's being pulled in by my `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: You need to enable SSl within your spring boot application... Find it out in `spring.rabbitmq.ssl.enabled=true` or equivalent YAML config.

Answer (score 0):

You can run docker with this command to use the default value :

```
docker run -it --rm --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```